# Ubuntu 18.04 Battery issue

Tags: 18.04, power-management, battery

I am having Acer machine currently installed Ubuntu 18.04. 
After I fully charge battery it works fine till around 45 - 50 % but after that it suddenly drops down to 1 - 2 % and notification popups of saying that battery is critically-low, your PC is about to hibernate.

If I plugin and recharge till then same thing happens, but If I continue using without plugging in then it continues for around 30-40 minutes even after 0 % battery.

Is there any issue with power management of Ubuntu OR it is the battery behaving weirdly.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, actually it was battery's problem but it is also true that somehow Ubuntu drops our battery capacity comparing to Windows

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu definitely has problems with the batteries of some laptops. I'm having Lenovo X230T and experiencing problems, identical with these described in the question. No matter whether the battery is a new or the old one. And none of the battery tools (as `tlp` that has extended support for ThinkPad) helped me to solve this.

The workaround that I found is:

> Always discharge the battery under 5% before start a new charge, then the new charge must be up to the maximum capacity - 100% for new battery.

With this small inconvenience the battery has the same life expectancy per charge as in Widows.

Comment: I bought a new machine and I will definitely try this thing. thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Install this application. It will sure help you to increase battery life. It's working very good on my ASUS FX553VD.

Install **slimbookbattery** application. And choose mode as per your works need. It's a one of the best solution or I can say battery saver tool that I was found out on net. And thanks to it's creator group.

**To Install:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:slimbook/slimbook
sudo apt update    
sudo apt install slimbookbattery
```

**To un-Install:**

```
sudo apt remove --auto-remove slimbookbattery
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:slimbook/slimbook
```